# Associating asp-button in gridview with code-behind function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, vb.net-2010

I am new to Vb.net.
I am using gridview and binding it a resultset from database. I am trying to use asp button and associate a codebehind function with it.

But since the rows are generating dynamically, ids of button are incrementing accordingly.

Here is the code -

```
'<asp:GridView ID="grdProjects" runat="server" CssClass="q_acontent" Width="990px"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="2" ClientIDMode="static" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Document Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text='<%# (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Data_text")))%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="conatact_phone  breakword" />
</asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>'
```

Please help me how to associate codebehind function and pass its corresponding button text to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OnCommand` event of button controls and Set the `CommandArgument` property of the button to your DataItem value as:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" 
 Text='<%# (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Data_text")))%>'
 OnCommand="Button3_Command" 
 CommandArgument='<%# (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
                  "Data_text")))%>'
        />
</ItemTemplate>
```

`OnCommand` event in your code behind file:

```
Public Sub Button3_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    Dim _dataText As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()

End Sub
```